# jquery tabs with sortables in separate files

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable

According to this page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

I can have the content of tabs in separate files.  Meaning that I just need to have the following HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab" id="tab_1"><a href="sortable-0.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</tab>
```

where sortable-0.html just contains:

```
<div class="column" id="column_1">

    <div class="portlet" id="portlet_1">
        <div class="portlet-header">Home 1</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="column" id="column_2">

</div>

<div class="column" id="column_3">

</div>
```

But when I do this, the sortables stop working.  If I copy the sortable HTML back into the original file, it starts working again.

Here is the current script where the code is all in 1 file, so the link below will work.  However, I can't get it to work if I move the sortable HTML into another file, then stick the URL of the new file into the following section of the jquery ui tabs html:

```
<li class="tab" id="tab_1"><a href="sortable-0.html">Home</a></li>
```

The link with the currect working example is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/ZjXz6/

Comment: you need to wrap `.column` with another div... so the wrapper is sortable and `.column` are its items to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to understand how JS works... if you call .sortable() function, it will search your page for all elements with class "portlet" and make em sortable.

BUT: With Ajax you do this: Load Page, your sortable function is called, it will search all elements of class "portlet" and make em sortable, THEN you load your content via ajax... your previous call of sortable is not valid for your new content. This means, if you load data via ajax, you need to call .sortable() again AFTER content have been loaded successfully :)

Look if you can add something like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        success: function(){
            $(".column").sortable({
                connectWith: '.column'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to replace your $("#tabs").tabs(); with the code i posted :)

Comment: That works, but it seem to reload the tab content every time a tab is clicked.  The default behavior just loads a tab once per session, which can be clicked on many times without doing another round trip to the server.

Comment: Nevermind, added the cache: true option and it is working how i wanted it to work!  Thanks.